# Sci-fi film or TV episode ending with a female astronaut turing into an alien, fish-like creature

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, tv

I'm trying to help a friend. He wants to find the name of an old sci-fi film. Supposedly, it should be from the '60s-'70s, maybe an *Alien* rip-off, but he only recalls the ending.

After a space journey, a group of astronauts were celebrating the defeat of an enemy/monster. They were eating and drinking happily and suddenly one of the astronauts, a woman, starts having convulsions; her ears shrank, gills appeared on her neck, and she ends turning into an alien, fish-like monster. End credits.

We've googled it without luck. Maybe it could be from an anthology sci-fi TV series instead, like *The Twilight Zone*? I don't know.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Did your friend actually watch this in the '60s/'70s, or is that just an estimate as to when it was made? IF they watched it more recently, we'd appreciate knowing the approximate the year in which they saw it, so that we have a clearer idea of how new it could possibly be.

Comment: Long shot, but the celebration and the appearance of the woman remind me of Species. Plot is not really right, but a woman does transform and the group of "monster hunters" are at one point at a hotel, celebrating, believing the monster is dead.

Comment: He watched it in his childhood, let's say twenty/twenty five years ago or so. But he recalls that it should be a 60s/70s film

Comment: Someone suggested it could be _Terror Beneath The Sea_ (1966), but that film ends with a happy ending instead of a cliffhanger

Comment: @Pelle - Was it in colour or black & white? (I'm guessing in colour, but it'd be good to confirm that.)

Comment: @LogicDictates In color

Comment: @Pelle - That rules out the older ('50s/'60s) runs of shows like _The Twilight Zone_ and _The Outer Limits_ then. If this was an episode from either of those shows, it'd have to be from the later runs in the '80s/'90s.

Comment: It can't be an Alien ripoff if it was from the 1960s or 70s

Comment: I am reminded of Terror Beneath the Sea (1966) which I have not seen in decades.  Replace the space stuff with underwater stuff.  The girl starts turning into a fish-person at the end.  It's spectacularly bad and well worth seeing.  https://notthistimenaylandsmith.blogspot.com/2021/08/terror-from-beneath-sea-1966.html

Comment: It's really quite terrible.  Full video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QLKXsS_Qjrw